# How Do I combine these two functions in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, function, click

These 2 functions do the exact same thing. They clear my array that takes in cache data. Its also hides the text that was there before and also hides the button itself.

How can I make one generic function and pass those same parameters in jQuery because they both target specific IDs????

```
            var CleartblCMRAssoc_click = function () {
            $('#btnCleartblCMRAssoc').offOn('click', function (event) {
                $('#tblCMRAssociation').igGridFiltering('filter', [], true);
                $('#spanCMRAssocDetailId').text('');
                $('#btnCleartblCMRAssoc').hide();
                return false;
                });
             }; 

        
         var ClearfldsetTTT_click = function () {
            $('#btnClearfldsetTTT').offOn('click', function (event) {
                $('#tblTTT').igGridFiltering('filter', [], true);
                $('#spanfldsetTTTDetailId').text('');
                $('#btnClearfldsetTTT').hide();
                return false;
            }); 
          };
```

Comment: Replace unique variable names and function names.  Is the HTML easier for YOU to read?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function by replacing all IDs with parameters and then call it for each set of IDs:

```
function genericFunction(firstId, secondId, thirdId, fourthId) {
    $(firstId).offOn('click', function (event) {
        $(secondId).igGridFiltering('filter', [], true);
        $(thirdId).text('');
        $(fourthId).hide();
        return false;
 });
}
```